# Conditionally adding patternset to fileset

Tags: nant

I want to add an exclusion list, if and only if the paternset actually exists.  I wasn't sure how to check if a patternset exists, so I added a regular property to serve as a flag.

```
<echo message="${property::exists('package.processSpecials')}" />
<fileset id="subprojects" basedir="${build.workspace}" >
    <include name="*" />
    <patternset refid="package.excludespecials" if="package.processSpecials" />
</fileset>
```

This fails because package.excludespecials does not exist, even though package.processSpecials does not exist.

```
[echo] False

BUILD FAILED

...package.build(288,10):
patternset reference 'package.excludespecials' not defined.
```

I tried putting an if statement inside the fileset definition, but it was an unexpected element.

My other alternative that feels a bit clunky is:

```
<if test="${property::exists('package.processSpecials')}">
    <fileset id="subprojects" basedir="${build.workspace}" >
        <include name="*" />
        <patternset refid="package.excludespecials" />
    </fileset>
</if>

<if test="${not property::exists('package.processSpecials')}">
    <fileset id="subprojects" basedir="${build.workspace}" >
        <include name="*" />
    </fileset>
</if>
```

Comment: Switching the parameters didn't work:  
        <patternset if="package.processSpecials" refid="package.excludespecials" />

Comment: I know NAnt is kinda outdated, but I'm updating an outdated process...

Comment: Have you tried always defining the package.excludespecials rather than just defining it conditionally? After all, it is just a definition... it doesn't actually do anything itself. That way, your first approach might work.

Comment: Possible, but I'd have to edit all the targets in the whole file, and in each place I'd have to check that it didn't already exist first.

Comment: I suppose I could just put a check on `${property::exists('package.processSpecials')}` right before I use it and populate it with empty?